# como trabajar directamente con queryset en django

Tags: python, django

Estimados estoy haciendo un llamado a un registro de mi tabla Clientes con `objects.filter` el cual me arroja un `queryset` en la variable cliente, puedo trabajarla con un `for`, pero no puedo trabajarla directamente con un `if`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from gestionClientes.models import Clientes


def login(request):
    return render(request, "login_t.html")

def login_res(request):

    if request.GET["rut"]:

        #mensaje="Rut a buscar: %r" %request.GET["rut"]
        rut=request.GET["rut"]
        
        cliente=Clientes.objects.filter(rut=rut)

        for cli in cliente:
        
            mensaje="Algo malo esta pasando" + " " + cli.group

        return HttpResponse(mensaje)            

    else:

        mensaje="No has ingresado nada"

    return HttpResponse(mensaje)
```

Comment: Muestra donde quiere poner el `if`

Comment: que reemplace el 

for cli in cliente:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cliente` es un `iterable`. Deberia llamarse clientes.
Si estas seguro de que el `filter` contiene sólo el objeto que necesitas. Entonces haz esto

```
cliente = Clientes.objects.filter(rut=rut).first()
if clinete.group == ...
```

Para el caso de que el queryset no contenga registros deberías de hacer un `try/except`